# WPF RichTextBox how to insert text in certain line and preserve color

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

WPF RichTextBox seems don't have Lines property so I can't use richTextBox.Lines. My workaround is to save all line's content into a list, insert some value to this list, clear richTextBox, and add the list to richTextBox.
For example, if I want to add some text at the second last row and color it red:

```
//insert value into the list 
lineContent.Insert(lineContent.Count - 1, value.ToString("X4"));
WhichLineIsChangedGlobal = lineContent - 2;
//clear the richTextBox
richTextBox.ClearText();
//copy the entire list to richTextBox line by line
for (int pos = 0; pos < lineContent.Count; pos++)
{
    richTextBox.SetText(lineContent[pos]);
}
//Color Red to the add line
richTextBox.ColorSelectLine(WhichLineIsChangedGlobal, "Red");
richTextBox.ScrollToEnd();
```

However, when I add some text into richTextBox one more time, the colored line will recover to black due to richTextBox.ClearText().

Is there any way to insert some value into RichTextBox without loosing the current value and property(like color, font)?

The ClearText function is here:

```
public static void ClearText(this RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
}
```

Comment: The `RichTextBox` content is `FlowDocument` and this means, for example, that one paragraph can fit few lines or one line, depend on current page width. What is requirement in your case? When text of one paragraph was splitting in few lines this still counting as one line or lines count corresponded to lines count after splitting of this paragraph on the page?

Comment: You should create a TextRange for each insertion. Then format each insertion as required. You can follow the redbone from the TextRange API documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textrange.load?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples. If you don't require the just to edit the formatted text, you should definitely consider to use a TextBlock instead of the RichTextBox. Also consider to use a StringBuilder to compose a big string that consists of lines and add it at once using a MemoryStream and TextRange.Load (like in the example) to improve performance.